# PayPal billing plan creation in live environment

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I am using **java SDK** for integrating PayPal in my project. I have used **sandbox** mode for creating **billing plans** for **recurring payments**. Now I have the live credentials, do I need to create my **billing plans** again in **live** mode?
Is there any **migration process** so that my **billing plans** for testing purposes can be used in **production environment** too?

Answer (score 0):

You have create them yourself in live; there is no migration path.

The live and sandbox environments are completely, 100% separate by design.

Comment: Thanks. After some researching and seeing the SDK codebase I think too that I have to create those plans again in live.